OrderBy with DoctrineExtensions Translatable
I already searched in doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions issues and doctrine/orm issues.
I use DoctrineExtensions to translate an entity, writing works fine so far.
Now I want achieve findAll() ordered by translated name.
$this->entityManager->getRepository(self::ENTITY_TYPE)->findBy([], ['name'=>'asc'])

This does not affect the result, but makes sense for me because DoctrineExtensions does not use classical ORM annotation mapping.
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

#[ORM\Entity()]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`my_table`')]
class MyEntity
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "uuid")]
    private string $id;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    #[Gedmo\Translatable]
    private string $name;
    
    // ..

I had the idea to join the translation table to the entity, for then ordering by joined translations, like that:
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->getRepository(self::ENTITY_TYPE)->createQueryBuilder('topic');
$queryBuilder->join(Translation::class, 'translation', 'with', 'translation.foreignKey = topic.id');
// ..
$entities = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

But this gives me following error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = uuid
(PostgreSQL)
DoctrineExtensions created the translation table with the foreignKey field of type character varying. The entity ID I use is of type uuid.
With a bit of research, I should have to cast either translation.foreignKey or topic.id.
When I try translation.foreignKey:uuid, I get error: Class Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Translation has no field or association named foreignKey:uuid
When I try CAST(translation.foreignKey as VARCHAR) or CAST(topic.id AS UUID), I get error: Error: Expected known function, got 'CAST'
My next Idea would be (quick'n dirty) to write the SQL by hand, getting the list of uuids and make a findBy() with in(uuid's), but if possible I want to avoid that.
Any ideas?
